# Pass Credentials to WMI Call in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, wmi, credentials, hta

I have VBScript inside a HTA getting the ping status from a local WMI call.. I also have a function to get the last reboot time of the remote pc..

```
Function GetReboot(strComputer)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject _
        ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
        dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime
        dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
        dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)
        Wscript.Echo dtmSystemUptime
    Next
    GetReboot = dtmLastbootupTime
End Function
```

That is roughly what it is, obviously i declare the variables and have another date function etc..

This works if I WMI call "localhost" as I am a local admin.. however when doing the WMI call to a remote server this only works if I am logged in to my local machine with an AD admin account.

Is there a way I can prompt the user for a username and password and then pass that to the WMI call so it works as anyone just with the admin details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the [SWbemLocator.ConnectServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720(VS.85).aspx) Method allows you to specify a username and password when connecting to remote computers.  It looks like the syntax that you need to use is similar, you just need to create your `objWMIService` object differently:

```
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer("MachineName", "root\cimv2", "Username", "Password")
```

More documentation is available if you search for "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator" on Google

Comment: Hi Kragen, thank you for the response, are you able to tell me if its possible to debug this? i have implemented this into my code and i get no errors.. however i still dont get a response and therfore access denied. If i run it while i am logged on as the admin account it works fine...

Comment: @medoix - If you run with script debugging enabled then you should be able to place a `Stop` statement at the front of your function to force a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As a domain admin, you would be able to add an additional right to your account, which would allow you to start processes as any other user. This right in AD is called "Allow User to be Trusted for Delegation". It is extremely powerful. It is the only legitimate way to run your task as another user. See this link to set the right:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932455