# Passing a password as a script parameter -- is it safe?

Tags: security, vbscript, passwords

My script is going to use WMI to connect to remote systems and I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929873/pass-credentials-to-wmi-call-in-vbscript) on how to go about doing so. It looks like I may need to pass in the username and password.

I am executing my script on remote systems with a Java program that runs it and parses the STDIN output.

Is it safe to pass in a password as a variable?

From the Java side the password will be in a property file (or a different method -- I'm not yet sure the best way to go about that, but its a different story) and I'll pass it in when I call the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never ever send passwords in plain. Use always a one way hash algorithm like [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) to encrypt the password entered by a user.

Further never save a password as plain text anywhere. Always store the hash and compare this with the hashed input of the user.

Some articles to start with VBScript:

- [Is there a method to encrypt passwords stored in a VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984710/is-there-a-method-to-encrypt-passwords-stored-in-a-vbs)
- [Encrypting/Hashing plain text passwords in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287517/encrypting-hashing-plain-text-passwords-in-database?rq=1)
- http://www.edugeek.net/forums/coding/6951-masking-password-inputbox-vbscript.html
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1d132da1-2014-4f34-87f5-d787e764995f/save-encrypted-password-in-vbscript

Comment: MD5 isn't really ideal either since it is insecure.

Comment: So would I just pass the encrypted version in the script and decrypt it right before sending it where it needs to go?

Comment: No. You don't decrypt the password (if it's possible to decrypt so it is not save)! You compare only the encrypted values, while using such algorithm (MD5 or better: a saver one! thanks to Darren Davies)

Comment: Nothing wrong with sending plaintext passwords when the connection is encrypted. Basically you have 2 options: a) send the unencrypted password and have the server check it against a stored hash or b) send a hash and have the server compare it against the hash of a stored plaintext password. Otherwise a transmitted hash would be the exact same as transmitted plaintext. Besides, you're not always free what to provide as it depends on what the server allows/requires, so sometimes you have to store the plain password in your script. Also, **DO NOT** use home-grown encryption algorithms. **EVER.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about sending the password in plaintext via network for a WMI request:
       This link says that if you have Kerberos authentication in use, password/username 
       cannot be intercepted on the network.
       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393720(v=vs.85).aspx
       Check if this helps you out.

If you are worried about saving the password on the machine (which you want use for a WMI request):
       Encrypt it and store in some db/file, decrypt it whenever you want to send it across
       And yes, you should use existing standard encryption mechanisms.